# Find substring of a string using Batch file scripts

Tags: windows, batch-file, substring

I have filenames consisting of a number, a space and a name.  For example, `"023 filename1.txt"`.

I want to create a Batch script which renames such files.  It needs to identify the sub-strings and remove everything before the space character.  For example, `"023 filename1.txt"` would be renamed to `"filename1.txt"`.

Please explain how to do this in a Batch file.

Comment: Do you want to rename the sample file to `filename1.txt` or `filename.txt`?

Comment: Thanks for the timely comment. I've edited above.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
   set newName=%%a
   ren "%%a" "!newName:* =!"
)
```

This part: `"!newName:* =!"` mean "take newName variable and replace from the beginning of its value until the space with nothing", that is, eliminate the beginning until the first space.

Answer (score 1):

This only echoes the commands it would execute.  Remove the echo on the third line to actually do the rename.

```
@echo off
for %%F in (*.txt) do (
  for /F "tokens=1,*" %%I in ("%%F") do echo ren "%%F" "%%J"
)
```

The first `for` iterates over all the `.txt` files.

The second `for` splits each file name into the initial number and the rest using `tokens=1,*`.  `%I` gets the number (which is ignored) and `%J` gets the new file name.

Comment: This can also remove multiple spaces between the number and the rest of the name, which may be even better.